# ArrayList-"for-loop" exits code at .size() call, what's wrong?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

As part of the login method for my fictive bank, i have a [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) set up to validate the users ID.

It seems to check through and comes back valid, but when i list the `ArrayList` (with the `for`-loop) to see if there's a corresponding match or not, the code seems to breaks out when it hits `kList.size()`

See this :

```
    public void logIn() {
        System.out.print("Please enter your ID (10 numbers):");
        String x = s.nextLine();
        if (luhnCheck(x)) {
                for (i = 0; i < k.kList.size(); i++) { //<-----ISSUE!
                    if (k.kList.get(i).getPnr().equals(x)) {
                        tempKund = k.kList.get(i);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("You are not a customer, please register!");
                System.out.print("Enter name:");
                String n = s.nextLine();
                k.createKund(x, n); //sends values to create customer method
                kundMeny1(); // customer menu...
        }
    }
    public boolean luhnCheck(String v) {
        int sum = 0;
        boolean alternate = false;
        for (int i = v.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int n = Integer.parseInt(v.substring(i, i + 1));
            if (alternate) {
                n *= 2;
                if (n > 9) {
                    n = (n % 10) + 1;
                }
            }
            sum += n;
            alternate = !alternate;
        }
        return (sum % 10 == 0);
    }
```

Update: So apparently the problem doesn't seem to in the loop, but when the .size() tries to get the needed information. I'll paste some more of my code:

```
public class Bank {
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
Kund k = new Kund(); //Used for communicating with the Kund(customer class)
Konto t = new Konto(); //Used for communicating with the Konto(account class)
Kund tempKund; //Temporary customer used to keep track of who's logged in
int i;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bank b = new Bank();
    b.mainMenu();
}
public void mainMenu() {
    k.createKund("8908041207", "Adam Sears"); //Creates a customer 
    t.createKonto("1234567891", "3000"); //Creates a bank account
    int user_choice = 3;
    do { // Goes on to a Switch Case menu for the user...
```

Kund(Customer class)

```
public class Kund {
ArrayList<Kund> kList = new ArrayList<Kund>();
Kund knd;
String pnr; //Customer ID, used in validation
String name; //Customer name

public void kund() {
}
public String getPnr() {
    return pnr;
}
public void setPnr(String x) {
    this.pnr = x;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String z) {
    this.name = z;
}
public void createKund(String p, String n) { //Creates the new customer
    knd = new Kund();
    knd.setPnr(p);
    knd.setName(n);
    addKund(knd);
}
public ArrayList<Kund> addKund(Kund s) { //Adds said customer to ArrayList
    kList.add(s);   
    return kList;
}
```

Comment: What is the k reference?

Comment: Tracing the code with a debugger is the way to find the problem source

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code :

```
    if (luhnCheck(x)) {
        if (true) {
          // Code
        } else if (false) {
          // Code
        }
    }
```

Should be replaced by this :

```
    if (luhnCheck(x)) {
        // Code
    } else {
        // Code
    }
```

For the rest of the problem. I should know where you instantiate your `k` object.

Comment: Thank you for your time Yassin. It didn't solve the problem, my code still skips over and goes back to main menu. I'll update the question with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

We need more inforation on how k is instantiate, try to organize you snippet code, and try to debug at the

```
 for (i = 0; i < k.kList.size(); i++) { //<-----ISSUE!
```

to see what kist contains?